# Problemas ao passar Query String como parametro no nodejs

Tags: node.js, http, express.js

Estou tentando fazer a funcionalidade de `login` no `Nodejs`, para isso criei um método `get` que recebe o `email` e a senha como `Query String` e realiza uma consulta no banco de dados (`MySQL`) verificando se existe algum `ID` com esses dados, porém, a requisição fica ***aguardando*** eternamente e nada acontece :(

Já tentei de tudo e não consigo solucionar o problema.

Segue o meu código atual

Arquivo de funções que acessam o banco

```
async login(req,res) {

    let query = `select id from gerente where email = '${req.query.email}' and senha = '${req.query.senha}'`;
    await connection.query(query,(error,results,fields)=> {
        if(!error) {
            res.json(results)
        }
    })       
}
```

Arquivo de rotas que executa a função

```
routes.get('/api/colaboradores/login', colaboradoresController.login);
```

Observação: utilizo o express. Nomes de variáveis e a conexão com o banco de dados estão corretas, pois executo outras requisições do tipo `get`, `post`, `put` e `delete` e estão funcionando normalmente.

Comment: Poderia informar qual o valor de `error` e se não for nulo podeira também informar `error.sqlMessage`

Comment: coloquei um else para printar o valor de error, e ele não chega a printar nada, fica só carregando infinitamente rsrs. Utilizo o insomnia para fazer os testes

Comment: Você precisa usar o `verb` correto que é o `post`, e no estrutura de decisão precisa ter o `else` para capturar o error e também precisa ir debugando linha a linha, o problema é local não tem como a gente reproduzir

Comment: Porque post? O correto seria get não? preciso pegar o valor do id retornado

Comment: Só por curiosidade você levantou o servidor Mysql?

Comment: claro! o servidor mysql está funcionando. Eu consigo executar todas as outras funções (delete,put,post e outros gets) normalmente

Comment: No caso ai  o correto é post é um login, se não pode trafegar essa informação assim não. super errado.